# Handle Rdp ActiveX minimize event

Tags: c#, .net, activex, terminal-services

I've developed a simple .net form application where I've embedded the RdpClient ActiveX.
To reproduce the application, you have to:

- 'Add Reference' and select COM
- include 'Microsoft Terminal Services Control Type Library'
- select the ToolBox, 'Choose Items...' and go to 'COM Components' tab
- look for 'Microsoft RDP Client Control - version 6' (this is the version I've used)

Now you can drop this Control on the form.
Handle the form Shown event with this code

```
axMsRdpClient6.FullScreen = true;
axMsRdpClient6.Server = "yourserver";
axMsRdpClient6.Connect();
```

Then when the rdpclient window appear, click the minimize button on the top bar.

**My question is**: why the event AxMSTSCLib.AxMsRdpClient7.**OnRequestContainerMinimize is not fired** when minimize button is clicked?

I need to handle when the user minimize the client to take peculiar actions (write log files, activate other windows application and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381806.aspx)

> This method will only be called if the container-handled full-screen mode is enabled - see 
>   IMsTscAdvancedSettings::put_ContainerHandledFullScreen for more information.